# Display process consuming memory with CPU time

Tags: powershell

I am trying to display 10 processes which are consuming most memory in a system with cpu time by adding kernel mode time and user mode time of the process. but it is showing nothing.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -ComputerName XXXXX |
    Sort-Object WorkingSetSize -Descending |
    Select-Object -First 10 |
    Format-Table -AutoSize Name, ProcessID,
        @{Label = "Consumed Memory(MB)"; Expression = {
            [math]::Round(($_.WorkingSetSize/1MB), 2) }},
        @{Name = "Cpu Time"; Expression = {
            "{0:HH:mm:ss}" -f ([datetime]$ts = [timespan]::FromTicks($_.KernelModeTime + $_.UserModeTime)).Ticks }}
```

Output:

```
Name                         ProcessID Consumed Memory(MB) Cpu Time
----                         --------- ------------------- --------
SC.Server.WindowsService.exe     58400             2300.46
tesvc.exe                         1680              138.88
iisexpress.exe                   59004               98.61
java.exe                         39020               77.68
mcshield.exe                      2436               63.68
svchost.exe                        828               47.12
lsass.exe                          588               33.65
CcmExec.exe                       2496                20.8
svchost.exe                        692               14.34
svchost.exe                        796               14.14
```

could you please tell me what is wrong in this?

Comment: The errors you don't see look like this : `Cannot convert the "00:01:33.0156250" value of type "System.TimeSpan" to type "System.DateTime"`. They are caused by this part `[datetime]$ts = [timespan]::fromticks(...`. Not sure how to fix this, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your parentheses are off, and you need to remove the assignment operation. You need to cast the ticks of the `Timespan` value to a `DateTime` value.

Change this:

```
"{0:HH:mm:ss}" -f ([datetime]$ts = [timespan]::FromTicks($_.KernelModeTime + $_.UserModeTime)).Ticks
```

into this:

```
"{0:HH:mm:ss}" -f [datetime][timespan]::FromTicks($_.KernelModeTime + $_.UserModeTime).Ticks
```

If you're fine with getting fractions of a second as well you could also [format the `Timespan` directly](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/03/15/use-powershell-and-conditional-formatting-to-format-time-spans/):

```
'{0:c}' -f [timespan]::FromTicks($_.KernelModeTime + $_.UserModeTime)
```

Comment: awesome. Thanks a lot.